# Dynamically switch content/fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components

My app currently uses a navigation host (Android Architecture Components navigation) to switch between fragments. One of these fragments is a more complex form where I want to show/hide some content depending on whether `button 1` or `button 2` is pressed.

Here is a sketch of it:

[image]

How is that normally done in Android? Would I add a second navhost inside of the (blue background) fragment which itself is shown in a nav host? I am also using data binding, would I then have to use a second binding object for the fragments inside the second navhost or could they share a binding object with the "main" (blue background) fragment?

Or would it be better to just manually inflate the two fragments (the one for button1 and the one for button2)? But then, what would I use as container to host them?

Comment: This looks like a [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout). You can use it in the layout of some Fragment which will be managed by the Navigation framework (this means it will be put into the NavHostFragment). Inside this Fragment, you can add child Fragments to the TabLayout.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I intended to use a `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` (ToggleButton, Ctrl+F here: https://medium.com/over-engineering/hands-on-with-material-components-for-android-buttons-76fa1a92ec0a), which can be imagined as simply two buttons. How would I handle it in that case?

Comment: I think you can't have nested NavHostFragments. The Navigation framework assumes you have one Activity with one NavHostFragment. A NavHostFragment which contains another NavHostFragment sounds at least complicated... so I definitely recommend making the grey area a FrameLayout and using two child Fragments which your (blue) Fragment can manage by using the FragmentManager obtained via getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: You can certainly have nested NavHostFragments.

Comment: @ianhanniballake and 0X0nosugar: after doing more research I think I have at least 3 options: navhost, viewpager 2, fragment manager. the fragments I will exchange are relatively small (like maximum 5 views per fragment), so I though about caching/preloading them. I know that viewpager 2 is able to do that, how about navhost/navigation and fragment manager. Is preloading with them possible? I want smooth, fast switching between the two fragments.

Comment: If you use FragmentManager you can have the Fragments added to the back stack. This way, swapping Fragments should be fast (if there are only two, the one which is currently invisible may not even be destroyed any time soon as long as the parent Fragment stays in the foreground) That being said, it is generally a good idea to use a ViewModel (and a custom singleton class, a Repository where the app manages data) because that way you don't have to start loading data again (e.g. from the web) just because some UI component was destroyed

Comment: My favourite link: [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide)

Comment: thank you, architecture is already given (following the guide you mentioned). Adding to back stack is nothing I want, I am just changing small parts of the UI and not sure, what's the best practice for that \:

Comment: With just a handful of Views per Fragment I would not worry too much about performance (if you're not trying to do a TextView with an approximation of PI) BTW I figured out how to have a nested NavHostFragment. Since it's possible, I'd prefer it because it's better code style to not have  several approaches to do the same thing inside one app

Comment: ... and yet another idea if you're not satisfied with the smoothness of the transition: build a custom View of which only one half will be shown and on click let it slide to reveal the other half

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use the Navigation components for the main navigation, from a "clean architecture" point of view, it's desirable to use them for the navigation between the child `Fragment`s as well.

You can have a `NavHostFragment` inside a `Fragment`. The important thing is to not set         `app:defaultNavHost="true"` this time.

My sample app has a `FragmentB` with two children `FragmentB1` and `FragmentB2`.

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/childNavHostFragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toggleGroup"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/child_navigation" />
```

child_navigation.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/chlld__navigation.xml"
    app:startDestination="@+id/dest_fragment_b1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dest_fragment_b1"
        android:name="com.example.nestednavhostfragment.FragmentB1"
        android:label="FragmentB1" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dest_fragment_b2"
        android:name="com.example.nestednavhostfragment.FragmentB2"
        android:label="FragmentB2" />

    <action android:id="@+id/action_show_b1" app:destination="@+id/dest_fragment_b1"/>
    <action android:id="@+id/action_show_b2" app:destination="@+id/dest_fragment_b2"/>
</navigation>
```

With a `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` in the parent `FragmentB`, you can navigate using the `<action>` tags in the above navigation graph:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggleGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:checkedButton="@+id/button1"
        app:singleSelection="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/childNavHostFragment"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:text="Show B1"
            />
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Show B2"
         />
    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

`FragmentB` code, note that you need to "find" the correct `NavController` using the *childNavHostFragment* container

```
class FragmentB : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b_layout, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)
        val childNavController  = childNavHostFragment?.findNavController()
        button1.setOnClickListener {childNavController?.navigate(R.id.action_show_b1)}
        button2.setOnClickListener {childNavController?.navigate(R.id.action_show_b2)}
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks and sorry for the late reply. Could you extend your answer a little bit, what would happen if one would again set `app:defaultNavHost="true"`? What are the practical consequences?

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf - in my sample app, having a second NavHostFragment (inside Fragment B) with the attribute `app:defaultNavHost="true"` caused the BACK Button not to work any more (normally, one should be able to navigate from Fragment B to Fragment A by pressing BACK) . The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#add-navhostfragment) simply states that one should "be sure to specify only one default NavHost" per layout, presumably because one can't be sure which one will turn out to "really be" the one which can intercept the system BACK button